# Convertion Failure! Contact Server Admin. Error using OfficeConverter

Tags: php, laravel, controller, phpword, phpoffice

I wan´t to convert a .docx file into PDF. If I use The PhpOffice\PhpWord Libraries, i lose my styles, so i have tried with OfficeConverter, but i have this error:
"**Convertion Failure! Contact Server Admin.**"

I have this in my Controller

```
    $converter = new OfficeConverter(storage_path('./../MyFile.docx'));
    $converter->convertTo(storage_path('./../MyFile.pdf'));
```

Also in the header of this php file i have:

```
    use NcJoes\OfficeConverter\OfficeConverter;
    use PDF;
```

This "use PDF" is like that because i have declarated in Config\app.php the providers and the aliases

Anyone knows why i'm having this error? Thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Because OfficeConverter cant find `libreoffice` command in PATH. OfficeConverter `__construct` have `$bin = 'libreoffice'` param. Use it for pass path to you libreoffice installation.

MacOS example:

```
$converter = new OfficeConverter( 'filename.docx', null, '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the package source code in officeConverter.php you will notice  the $bin you need to add the path explicitly

```
public function __construct($filename, $tempPath = null, $bin = 'libreoffice', $prefixExecWithExportHome = true)
{
    if ($this->open($filename)) {
        $this->setup($tempPath, $bin, $prefixExecWithExportHome);
    }
}
```

Add this line and it should work

```
    $converter = new OfficeConverter( 'filename.docx', null, '/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice', true );
```